# Recurrence relation for ternary search

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence, ternary-search

The recurrence relation of ternary search is T(n)= T(n/3) + 4, How 4 is in recurrence relation, since in ternary search it's log to the base 3 N, so only 3 partitions should be there ?

Comment: What's your source on this recurrence relation? That number 4 probably depends on some particular implementation being analyzed in a particular way.

Comment: There was a question that either binary search or ternary search takes more number of comparisons, and in the solution this recurrence relation is given, so i was figuring out, how they could have gotten the 4.

Comment: That recurrence relation is not correct for the algorithm normally referred to as 'ternary search'.  You are probably thinking of something else. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search

Comment: @Vedsinha Can you provide a direct link to that answer? That seems incorrect.

Comment: That's a test series, so if i will give the link, it will require credentials @templatetypedef

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yes, I got it, the recurrence is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Recurrence relation for ternary search is `T(n) = T(n/3) + O(1)` or even `T(n) = T(2n/3) + O(1)`. The constant hidden in this `O(1)` depends on concrete implementation and how analysis was conducted. It could be `4` or `3`, or some other value. Applying [case 2 of Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Case_2_example) you still have `O(log n)`.